# How to properly use user_access($string, $account) in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, url-routing

I would like to limit the use of some url's. Let's say `node/add` and `node/7` (just random examples). I'm thinking the best way to do this is to use the `user_access` function.

But as we are used to it, the Drupal documentation doesn't help much. When I just use the function, I get the message the function is already in use. So my best guess is to use this existing function with my own arguments in my custom function in my custom module.
But in this way I need to catch the page before loading it. Or I'm I missing something here?

**EDIT:**
I've set this

```
global $user;
$items['node/add/%']['access callback'] = array('_mymodule_node_access');
$items['node/add/%']['access arguments'] = array(0,2, $user);
```

But for some reason, Drupal isn't picking up the `%` card for all types. It's just working for one type (script). Other terms like page or fiche aren't getting picked up... `%` is a Drupal wildcard right?

**EDIT:**
I just found out there are already some paths in the database. How can I overwrite them? What I need is *one* selector which can select all four content types (fiche, page, script and news-item).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to define a particular access function for a path is to set the `access callback` for the path's menu item in `hook_menu()`. This is slightly different for existing paths, in that you need to implement `hook_menu_alter()` to edit the existing `access callback` for that path:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/add']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_node_add_access_callback';
}

function mymodule_node_add_access_callback() {
  // return TRUE to allow access, FALSE to deny
}
```

This gets a bit more fun when we're talking about node pages as their menu items is defined using a wildcard `node/%`. This means that using `hook_menu_alter()` you can only change the access callback for all nodes.

Fortunately Drupal has a [`hook_node_access`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) hook to come to the rescue:

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $restricted_nids = array(7, 10, 12);

  if (in_array($node->nid, $restricted_nids) && $op == 'view') {
    if ($some_condition_is_true) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }

    return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
  }

  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Hope that helps

**EDIT**

If that all seems like a bit much hassle you might get some joy installing the [Path Access module](http://drupal.org/project/path_access), I think it has the functionality you're after.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

I *think* the reason overriding the wildcard isn't working in this case is because the node module explicitly defines a path for each node type, e.g. `node/add/page`, `node/add/article`, etc. Because Drupal will take an exact match (`node/add/page`) over a wildcard match (`node/add/%`) you're actually overriding the wrong menu item.

Try specifying the path explicitly in your `hook_menu_alter()` function (note that the `access callback` should be a string and not an array as you currently have):

```
$items['node/add/page']['access callback'] = '_mymodule_node_access';
$items['node/add/page']['access arguments'] = array(0,2, $user);
```

It's also worth noting that the `$user` object you're passing will always be the user object of the logged in user *who cleared Drupal's caches* (since menu items are rebuilt when the cache is rebuilt). If you're looking to pass the *current* logged in user (i.e. the one logged in at the time the page is accessed) that's a different thing altogether...I'd advise asking another question on it as it can be a tricky bugger and you want to get as much input as possible from people on here.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer. Could you take a look at my edit in my question please?

Comment: I added an image, hope it makes sense for you :)

Comment: @Michiel: I've added a bit more hope it helps :)

Comment: thanks for the edit. I think I learned more of Drupal from you then from the Drupal documentation! ;-) Especially the `$user` part about clearing the menu is very interesting and enlightened! Thanks a lot